# How to mount a specific file within a pod folder in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, configmap

I run Jenkins in k8s, and I have mount /var/jenkins_home folder with PVC already, now I want to mount /var/jenkins_home/config.xml as a configmap, other the folder still mount with pvc.

below is my yaml file:

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      name: jenkins-data
      subPath: jenkins
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home/config.xml
      name: configxml
      subPath: config.xml

  volumes:
  - name: jenkins-data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: shdr-jenkins-k-test
  - name: configxml
    configMap:
      name: jenkins-k-config
      ites:
      - key: jenkins-configfile
        path: config.xml
```

when I open jenkins, it says:

```
Also:   java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/jenkins_home/atomic14997153162086721303tmp -> /var/jenkins_home/config.xml: Device or resource busy
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.commit(AtomicFileWriter.java:194)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/jenkins_home/config.xml: Device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

You need to set the mountPath of `jenkins-data` volume to be `/var/jenkins_home/jenkins`. This will correctly configure the `subPath` functionality.

### Detailed Explanation

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to achieve is the following:

1. You have a `ConfigMap` named `jenkins-k-config`. This contains a single parameter `config.xml` with contents of your Jenkins configuration as a value.
2. You want to mount this `ConfigMap` at the path `/var/jenkins_home/` in your Jenkins pod, so the pod can use the `/var/jenkins_home/config.xml` file.

Here's how you can do this:

1. You will update your pod specification to add the `ConfigMap` as a volume.
2. You will then add a `volumeMount` to mount that the contents of that `ConfigMap` into the specified mount point in your pod's container.

Since your `ConfigMap` only contains a single key named `config.xml`, you don't have to specify the `items` anyway. Simply mounting the `ConfigMap` will work. See the manifest below:

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /var/jenkins_home/
      name: configxml
      subPath: config.xml
      readOnly: true.  #<==== Recommended, so config remains immutable.
  volumes:
  - name:configxml
    configMap:
      name: jenkins-k-config
```

I also noticed that when all these mistakes have been fixed, we will end up with 2 volumes (jenkins-data, configxml) attempting to mount to the same `mountPoint` inside the pod. This is the reason you're seeing `device or resource busy` error, since the mountPoint is already busy, being mounted with the `jenkins-data` volume.

You can change the mount point to `/var/jenkins_home/jenkins`. This will also put your `subPath` variable in affect and you will be able to mount both volumes.

`jenkins-data` ====> `/var/jenkins_home/jenkins` and

`config.xml` ====> `/var/jenkins_home/config.xml`.